# How to remove part of string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In one table of my database I have strings which looks like this one:

```
sometext-othertext
```

How to remove the text including dash with SELECT statement so the result to be just `sometext`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Return the substring before the first occurrence of the delimiter "-":

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo-bar-bar', '-', 1) as result;`

Outputs result = "foo"

You can replace 1 with the numbers of occurrences you want before getting the substring

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo-bar-bar', '-', 2) as result;`

Outputs result = "foo-bar"

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Reference - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 9):

<strike>SELECT REPLACE("sometext-othertext","-", "") as newvalue</strike>

This should do it.

Edit:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('sometext-othertext', '-', 1) as newvalue;
```

apologies for not understanding the question earlier.

Comment: No, this will produce `sometextothertext` while OP wants `sometext`.

Comment: Sorry - replied hastily I guess! 
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('sometext-othertext', '-', 1) as newvalue;

Answer (score 5):

have two ways to use troubleshooting this, if you like to display all (only just remove "-" symbol, i recommended use this because have more speed:

```
SELECT REPLACE('sometext-othertext','-','');
```

that syntax change text "-" to "" (empty text because you want  just remove that)

if you want to display only part one (ex :sometext) or just part two (ex :othertext) you can use this, for spliting string:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('sometext-othertext', '-', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('sometext-othertext', '-', 1);
```

Function have 3 prameters, first that is a text, second is object for spliting, and number (1) for getting you want (the controller)

Answer (score 0):

better use mysql REPLACE function to replace "-" with ""

Comment: That is not the entire goal. Everything following the first dash should be removed.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.