# MYSql left join two tables with column different values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables
1: tbl_member_registration with primary key (mem_id)
2: tbl_phone with foreign key (parent_code)

I want to left join these two tables but tbl_phone parent_code column has different values starting with prefix **mem_** , how to join these two tables?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does your values have a prefix in your second table? Seems like you should sort that out first. You also have rows where the values have `cmp_*`. I'm guessing that this is some multipurpose-table where "parent_code" cant link to different tables? That's a bad design. Let each entity type have their own table.

Comment: To apply joins both the tables have similar type value for primary key and foreign key. You need to remove mem_ from the parent_code column of tbl_phone to apply left join with tbl_member_registration.

Comment: you need to join with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481361/how-to-remove-part-of-string-in-mysql

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave - No, it's better to sort bad design out _as soon as possible_ before the application grows and you have scattered hacky solutions all over your app. I recently had to deal with a large database which had this exact kind of tables and it was a total mess.

Comment: For next time, no images thanks . Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following join:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_member_registration t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_phone t2
    ON t1.mem_id = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.parent_code, '_', -1) AS SIGNED);
```

### Demo

Going forward, you may want to clean up your tables such that the join condition can be had using equality `=`.  There is no chance of an index being used on the `parent_code` column when it is being wrapped in an ugly call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

Comment: I think this makes sense, i was about to answer the same. Thank you

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave We could also just use substring, but substring_index makes it a little easier.

Comment: Exactly Tim .. Spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked it but you can try this will work.

```
select *
from tbl_member_registration tmr join tbl_phone tp
on tp.parent_code = concat('mem_',tmr.mem_id)
```

For more reference detail: [**CONCAT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,its working..

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl_member_registration t1
    INNER JOIN tbl_phone t2
        ON t1.mem_id = SUBSTR(t2.parent_code,5, 2);
```

http://rextester.com/CSBZ60078

Comment: You can use SUBSTR function for this...It looks simple and understanding its working check the above link that i've attached above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl_phone.*, tbl_member_registration.*
from tbl_member_registration.mem_id 
left join tbl_phone on tbl_member_registration.mem_id = (select substring(tbl_phone.parent_code, 5,2) );
```

Comment: Why are you using a subquery for this operation? You should also explain how your solution works.

Comment: subquery is only to get the mem_id on parent_code since the parent_code have name in the front of the id. then only run the rest of the query.

Comment: `tbl_member_registration.mem_id = substring(tbl_phone.parent_code, 5,2)` would work fine